# xcode subproject Missing dependency target

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, subproject

I have three project A,B,C, where B has subproject A , and C has subproject A and subproject B. After I add project B to C, xcode said project B "Missing dependency target A". The project navigator looks like the picture  [image: project navigator]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved same issue by changing structure to something like this:

1. Remove subproject A from B;
2. Move subproject A upper than B in target depedencies of project C;
3. Add path to subproject A to headers search path of subproject B, if not added previosly.

It works because static library doesn't need to be linked with depedencies, before linking main binary. Only headers needed to build.